# Troubleshooting FileDialog trying to update textBox1

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I'm looking for an "aha!" moment troubleshooting why the following works in one project, but in building a newer, more efficient version the same structure does not update the text in textBox1 with the result of openFileDialog1.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    }
```

[image: fig 1 textBox1.Text working properly in the first project]

I copied and pasted my code from Project 1 to Project 2, so I'm just not sure where the breakdown could be. The rest of the project does execute properly, so openFileDialog1 is completing successfully and allowing me to click button2 to encode a valid RSS xml file from the input given in openFileDialog1. The only thing not working is textBox1.Text displaying the FileName chosen in openFileDialog1. Any ideas as to where the breakdown is are appreciated!

Comment: Is `openFileDialog1_FileOk()` actually bound to the file dialog and is it being called? Copying just the implementation may not include the event handler binding, which is typically in the designer file.

Comment: Good thought. I did build out the form first before moving the {openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();} and {textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;} over, getting all the text boxes and buttons working, but neglected to do the same for openFileDialog1 - good catch!